Maximum value over bi-monthly sliding window
I have a two-year daily time series that I would like to extract the maximum values from between two-month wide sliding windows (i.e., Jan-Feb, Feb-Mar,..., Nov-Dec). I can get close to an answer by using the packages tidyverse and slider however, the answer is not exact because not all months have the same number of days. Is there a way to extract the maximum value from a two-month wide sliding window that does not rely on setting a value for the number of days to look before and after?
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

# Example Daily Timeseries
set.seed(333)

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                 as.Date('2021-12-31'),
                 '1 day'),
  value = round(rnorm(731,100,33))
)

# Calculate maximum in 2-month (60-day) wide sliding window
# Must supply number of days before and after but months have different number of days
df %>%
  mutate(two_month_max = slider::slide_index_dbl(value, date, max, .before = 30, .after = 30)) %>%
  filter(day(date) == 1) %>%
  select(!value)
#>          date two_month_max
#> 1  2020-01-01           164
#> 2  2020-02-01           164
#> 3  2020-03-01           160
#> 4  2020-04-01           170
#> 5  2020-05-01           181
#> 6  2020-06-01           181
#> 7  2020-07-01           150
#> 8  2020-08-01           193
#> 9  2020-09-01           193
#> 10 2020-10-01           212
#> 11 2020-11-01           212
#> 12 2020-12-01           187
#> 13 2021-01-01           179
#> 14 2021-02-01           179
#> 15 2021-03-01           167
#> 16 2021-04-01           159
#> 17 2021-05-01           169
#> 18 2021-06-01           184
#> 19 2021-07-01           184
#> 20 2021-08-01           194
#> 21 2021-09-01           194
#> 22 2021-10-01           163
#> 23 2021-11-01           161
#> 24 2021-12-01           168

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0
EXTRA INFO: I have formatted the output above to resemble that of the El Niño/Southern Oscillation (ENSO) - Multivariate ENSO Index Version 2 (MEI) which these maximum values will be appended to at another time.
library(tidyverse)
library(rsoi)

# Import Multivariate ENSO Index Version 2 (MEI) ----
mei <- download_mei()

mei %>%
  arrange(-desc(Date))
#> # A tibble: 552 × 5
#>     Year Month Date         MEI Phase        
#>    <int> <fct> <date>     <dbl> <ord>        
#>  1  1979 DJ    1979-01-01  0.47 Neutral Phase
#>  2  1979 JF    1979-02-01  0.29 Neutral Phase
#>  3  1979 FM    1979-03-01 -0.05 Neutral Phase
#>  4  1979 MA    1979-04-01  0.21 Neutral Phase
#>  5  1979 AM    1979-05-01  0.27 Neutral Phase
#>  6  1979 MJ    1979-06-01 -0.11 Neutral Phase
#>  7  1979 JJ    1979-07-01 -0.11 Neutral Phase
#>  8  1979 JA    1979-08-01  0.47 Neutral Phase
#>  9  1979 AS    1979-09-01  0.38 Neutral Phase
#> 10  1979 SO    1979-10-01  0.23 Neutral Phase
#> # ℹ 542 more rows

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0

Here's an all tidyverse take (no zoo or slider).
library(tidyverse) # dplyr || lubridate || purrr
 
# `reframe` returns an arbitrary number of rows per group [1] -------------
new_df <- df %>% 
  reframe(
    start_date = unique(floor_date(date, "months")),
    interval   = as.interval(months(2) - days(1), start_date),
    max_value  = map_dbl(interval, \(x) max(keep(value, date %within% x))))

Output:
> new_df
   start_date                       interval max_value
1  2020-01-01 2020-01-01 UTC--2020-02-29 UTC       164
2  2020-02-01 2020-02-01 UTC--2020-03-31 UTC       160
3  2020-03-01 2020-03-01 UTC--2020-04-30 UTC       170
4  2020-04-01 2020-04-01 UTC--2020-05-31 UTC       181
5  2020-05-01 2020-05-01 UTC--2020-06-30 UTC       181
6  2020-06-01 2020-06-01 UTC--2020-07-31 UTC       150
7  2020-07-01 2020-07-01 UTC--2020-08-31 UTC       193
8  2020-08-01 2020-08-01 UTC--2020-09-30 UTC       193
9  2020-09-01 2020-09-01 UTC--2020-10-31 UTC       212
10 2020-10-01 2020-10-01 UTC--2020-11-30 UTC       212
11 2020-11-01 2020-11-01 UTC--2020-12-31 UTC       187
12 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 UTC--2021-01-31 UTC       179
13 2021-01-01 2021-01-01 UTC--2021-02-28 UTC       179
14 2021-02-01 2021-02-01 UTC--2021-03-31 UTC       167
15 2021-03-01 2021-03-01 UTC--2021-04-30 UTC       159
16 2021-04-01 2021-04-01 UTC--2021-05-31 UTC       169
17 2021-05-01 2021-05-01 UTC--2021-06-30 UTC       184
18 2021-06-01 2021-06-01 UTC--2021-07-31 UTC       184
19 2021-07-01 2021-07-01 UTC--2021-08-31 UTC       194
20 2021-08-01 2021-08-01 UTC--2021-09-30 UTC       194
21 2021-09-01 2021-09-01 UTC--2021-10-31 UTC       163
22 2021-10-01 2021-10-01 UTC--2021-11-30 UTC       161
23 2021-11-01 2021-11-01 UTC--2021-12-31 UTC       168
24 2021-12-01 2021-12-01 UTC--2022-01-31 UTC       168

[1] reframereference here.
Toy data:
# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
set.seed(333)

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2021-12-31'), '1 day'),
  value = round(rnorm(731,100,33)))

Created on 2024-05-10 with reprex v2.1.0

The help for slide_index has a similar example, suggesting an application here:
df %>%
  mutate(two_month_max = slider::slide_index_dbl(value, date, 
                                                 ~max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                                 .before = ~.x %m-% months(1), 
                                                 .after  = ~.x %m+% months(1))) %>% 
  filter(day(date) == 1) %>%
  select(!value)

From ?slide_index:
# Functions for `.before` and `.after`

# In some cases, it might not be appropriate to compute
# `.i - .before` or `.i + .after`, either because there isn't a `-` or `+`
# method defined, or because there is an alternative way to perform the
# arithmetic. For example, subtracting 1 month with `- months(1)` (using
# lubridate) can sometimes land you on an invalid date that doesn't exist.
i <- as.Date(c("2019-01-31", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-31"))

# 2019-03-31 - months(1) = 2019-02-31, which doesn't exist
i - months(1)

# These NAs create problems with `slide_index()`, which doesn't allow
# missing values in the computed endpoints
try(slide_index(i, i, identity, .before = months(1)))

# In these cases, it is more appropriate to use `%m-%`,
# which will snap to the end of the month, at least giving you something
# to work with.
i %m-% months(1)

# To use this as your `.before` or `.after`, supply an anonymous function of
# 1 argument that performs the computation
slide_index(i, i, identity, .before = ~.x %m-% months(1))

# Notice that in the `.after` case, `2019-02-28 %m+% months(1)` doesn't
# capture the end of March, so it isn't included in the 2nd result
slide_index(i, i, identity, .after = ~.x %m+% months(1))


It turns out that slide_period_dfr() can do exactly what I need.
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

# Example Daily Timeseries
set.seed(333)

df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                 as.Date('2021-12-31'),
                 '1 day'),
  value = round(rnorm(731,100,33))
)

# Expected output for first year
df %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-01-01') &
           date <= as.Date('2020-02-29')) %>%
  summarise(max(value))
#>   max(value)
#> 1        164

df %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-02-01') &
           date <= as.Date('2020-03-31'))  %>%
  summarise(max(value))
#>   max(value)
#> 1        160

df %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-03-01') &
           date <= as.Date('2020-04-30'))  %>%
  summarise(max(value))
#>   max(value)
#> 1        170

df %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-04-01') &
           date <= as.Date('2020-05-31'))  %>%
  summarise(max(value))
#>   max(value)
#> 1        181

df %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-05-01') &
           date <= as.Date('2020-06-30'))  %>%
  summarise(max(value))
#>   max(value)
#> 1        181

df %>%
  filter(date >= as.Date('2020-06-01') &
           date <= as.Date('2020-07-31'))  %>%
  summarise(max(value))
#>   max(value)
#> 1        150

output <- slide_period_dfr(.x = df$value,
                 .i = df$date,
                 .period = "month",
                 .f = max,
                 .before = 1,
                 .complete = TRUE)

head(output)
#>   ...1
#> 1  164
#> 2  160
#> 3  170
#> 4  181
#> 5  181
#> 6  150

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0

Use the fact that if u and v are vectors that max(c(u, v)) equals max(max(u), max(v)) so we can calculate the one month maxima and then calculate the two month maxima from those.  max1 and max2 are the one and two month maxima.
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(cut(date, "month"))) %>%
  summarize(max1 = max(value), .by = date) %>%
  mutate(max2 = rollapplyr(max1, 2, max, partial = TRUE))

giving
         date max1 max2
1  2020-01-01  164  164
2  2020-02-01  160  164
3  2020-03-01  154  160
4  2020-04-01  170  170
5  2020-05-01  181  181
6  2020-06-01  150  181
7  2020-07-01  149  150
8  2020-08-01  193  193
9  2020-09-01  189  193
10 2020-10-01  212  212
11 2020-11-01  187  212
12 2020-12-01  178  187
13 2021-01-01  179  179
14 2021-02-01  167  179
15 2021-03-01  159  167
16 2021-04-01  145  159
17 2021-05-01  169  169
18 2021-06-01  184  184
19 2021-07-01  150  184
20 2021-08-01  194  194
21 2021-09-01  163  194
22 2021-10-01  161  163
23 2021-11-01  147  161
24 2021-12-01  168  168

Note
Input from question
set.seed(333)
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                 as.Date('2021-12-31'),
                 '1 day'),
  value = round(rnorm(731,100,33))
)

